# How do we group monospace font families with regards to their serif property?

Tags: css, fonts, font-family, monospace

I am studying the `font-family` CSS property and I understand that the font families are grouped into 3 categories, which are called General Families:

1. Serif
2. Sans-Serif
3. Monospace

The question here is how do we group monospace font families with regards to their serif property? Is it always "serif"? Is it always "sans-serif"? Can I have monospace font families that are "serif" and some others that are "sans-serif"? Does a monospace font family use the "serif" property consistently on all of its characters so that it can be categorised as "serif" or "sans-serif"? Is there an official resource or specification about this subject?

Comment: Not really a solvable programming question....so probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: @Paulie_D I do not know whether it is "really a solvable programming question" but it already has 1 upvote and a very good answer, which I am considering. Also, I am trying to get the answer to this question so that I can solve programming problems and being able to apply correct CSS font families to my HTML pages. Surely, a programming context.

Comment: Upvotes and answers don't make it on-topic for SO. Perhaps other SE sites might be more appropriate.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, I believe my question is on topic. It is about "software tools commonly used by programmers". CSS is one of those. Also it is "practical". Obviously. It is "answerable" problem: Example of possible answers: "Yes monospace families can include both 'sans-serif' and 'serif' font families." or "No they cannot include" or "They include only sans serif". And it has to do with programming. (Although HTML / CSS are not programming languages in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS `font-family` property is only a **practical implementation** of a very broad and ancient art, namely ***[Typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography)***.

The generic font-family is a fallback for when the specified font is not installed on the system that's rendering the element, or for when the specified font file could not be loaded for any reason, in which case the generic font will be used.

Currently there are not 3, but 5 generic font-families commonly used by browsers:

- serif
- sans-serif
- monospace
- cursive
- fantasy

The default font used for each generic family varies depending on various browser/OS/device settings.

All this system was designed in the days when specifying an external (font-file) resource for rendering the text was not in practice and websites relied solely on fonts installed on the user's machine, so you have to regard it as a practical solution to ***decently cover* all possible situations** and, by no means, as an exhaustive or complete classification of fonts.

While most font types can be easily classified as belonging to one generic font family or another, others are displaying characteristics from multiple categories, much like a musical piece can belong to more than one genre.

Comment: Very informative answer. Thanks. So does that mean that when I specify "monospace" the font family finally chosen by the browser might be a font family that has either "serif" or "sans-serif" or a mixture of them, but still, it will preserve the main property of a "monospace" font (same width space for every character used)?

Comment: Basically, yes. You don't have two `monospace` default fonts, one `serif` and one `sans`. You have 5 defaults, one for each type. But nowadays you actually specify the resource that you want the browser to use to render the element. The browser will only decide in the very rare case that your page loads but the font file doesn't. What are the odds of that happening? 1 in a milion?